# cheking if the SSN number is correct

Tags: java

I searched for this question and got an answer from the "big moose saloon" website which is slightly different with what I wrote. the website programs like this:

```
if (social.length() == 11) {
  valid = true;
  // Check that the characters are valid
  // Valid as digits
  char index0 = social.charAt(0);
  char index1 = social.charAt(1);
  char index2 = social.charAt(2);
  char index4 = social.charAt(4);
  char index5 = social.charAt(5);
  char index7 = social.charAt(7);
  char index8 = social.charAt(8);
  char index9 = social.charAt(9);
  char index10 = social.charAt(10);
  // Valid as hyphen
  char index3 = social.charAt(3);
  char index6 = social.charAt(6);

  if (Character.isDigit(index0) && Character.isDigit(index1)
        && Character.isDigit(index2) && Character.isDigit(index4)
        && Character.isDigit(index5) && Character.isDigit(index7)
        && Character.isDigit(index8) && Character.isDigit(index9)
        && Character.isDigit(index10) && index3 == '-'
        && index6 == '-') {
     valid = true;
   }
} else
   valid = false;
return valid;
```

And mines is like this:

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your Social security number as DDD-DD-
    DDDD");
String str = input.nextLine();

if (str.length()==11) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input");

    if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))&&Character.isDigit(str.charAt(1))
     &&Character.isDigit(str.charAt(2))&&Character.isDigit(str.charAt(4))
     &&Character.isDigit(str.charAt(5))&&Character.isDigit(str.charAt(7))
     &&Character.isDigit(str.charAt(8))&&Character.isDigit(str.charAt(9))
     &&Character.isDigit(str.charAt(10))
     &&((str.substring(3,6)).startsWith("-")&&   
      ((str.substring(3,6)).endsWith("-"))) {

     System.out.println("The enter is valid");
    }
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("The enter is invalid");
  }
 }
}
```

I want to know why is my program wrong(even if I enter 123-45-6789 it also says "Invalid")?

Comment: The first one doesn't work either: it would return true for any 11-character string, e.g. "AAAAAAAAAAA".

Comment: @AndyTurner why ? cause I tried AAAAAAAAAAA, it says false

Comment: Because after `if (social.length() == 11) {`, `valid` is set to true, and never back to false again.

Comment: @AndyTurner yeah I think you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.substring(3,6).endsWith("-")` means substring from character 3 including to character 6 excluding. The first character in the original string is character 0.

Your second dash is at position 6, so you should do `substring(3,7)` instead.

Better solution would be to actually just check these two characters using `String#charAt(int)`. Just as in the solution you found on "big moose saloon".

And ideal solution would be to use regular expression. It will allow you to convert multiple lines of very difficult to read code that you have now into a single expression:

```
if (str.matches("\\d{3}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{4}")) {
    System.out.println("The enter is valid");
} else {
    System.out.println("The enter is invalid");
}
```

Comment: @pawlak Thank you very much! It turns out I made such a simple mistake. I changed my program as you said and it goes well.I have not learned regular expression yet but thanks for showing me this  ideal solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here change the code to this **just some minor changes**

**I have also mentioned the changes**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SSN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Social security number as DDD-DD-DDDD");
        String str = input.nextLine();

        if (str.length() != 11) {//use != in place of ==
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        } else if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(1))
                && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(2)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(4))
                && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(5)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(7))
                && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(8)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(9))
                && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(10))
                && (str.charAt(3) == '-') && (str.charAt(6) == '-')) {//use charAt()
            System.out.println("The enter is valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The enter is invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

---

***It will work fine.***

*But if you want the shortest possible code then use regex*

***Note:*** the code given below uses the syntax given by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1501234/jaroslaw-pawlak Please give credit to the original author if you use the code given below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SSN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Social security number as DDD-DD-DDDD");
        String str = input.nextLine();
        if (str.matches("\\d{3}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{4}")) {
            System.out.println("The enter is valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The enter is invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me that! I did find that if I enter 12-345-6789 it would give me neither valid nor invalid instruction. It seems my program has bug. I changed it as your idea and everything seems fine now.Than you!

Comment: Good. And it was a great thing that you marked the answer given by @pawlak as accepted. Proper credit must be given to original authors.